# From sigma finite it follows measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ be a measure space. Let $\mu^*: \mathcal A \rightarrow [0, \infty]$ be defined by: $\mu^*(A) = $sup$\{\mu(B): B \subset A, B \in \mathcal A, \mu(B) < \infty \}$.

Why does it hold true that if $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, it follows that $\mu^* = \mu$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $B\subseteq A$ then we have $\mu(B)\leq\mu(A)$. Hence if we take the supremum on the measures of such sets it will still be no more than $\mu(A)$. So that proves $\mu^*(A)\leq\mu(A)$.

For the other direction we have to use the fact that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite. We can write $X=\cup_{i=1}^\infty X_i$ where $\mu(X_i)<\infty$ for all $i$, and the sets in the union are pairwise disjoint. Then we get $A=\cup_{i=1}^\infty (A\cap X_i)$, and again the sets in the union are pairwise disjoint. Now note that for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ the set $\cup_{i=1}^n (A\cap X_i)$ is a measurable subset of $A$ which has finite measure, and hence:

$\sum_{i=1}^n\mu(A\cap X_i)=\mu(\cup_{i=1}^n (A\cap X_i))\leq\mu^*(A)$

Since this is true for all $n$ we conclude that $\mu(A)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\mu(A\cap X_i)\leq\mu^*(A)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! What if $A \in \mathcal A$ and $\mu(A) = 0$, if $A = \emptyset$ and $\mu(A) = \infty$, otherwise. What would, here, be the concrete measure $\mu^*$?

Comment: Well, in that case the only subset of $A$ with finite measure is the empty set, and it has measure zero. So $\mu^*(A)=0$.

Comment: Thank you for this reply!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, $\mu^{\ast}(A)\leq\mu(A)$. Now let $X=\displaystyle\bigcup_{n}X_{n}$, where $X_{n}\uparrow$, $\mu(X_{n})<\infty$. It is not hard to see that $\mu^{\ast}(A)=\lim_{n}\mu^{\ast}(A\cap X_{n})\geq\lim_{n}\mu(A\cap X_{n})=\mu(A)$.